# Problem with mongo AddFieldsOperation in java

Tags: java, regex, spring, mongodb, full-text-search

I have to filter documents by multiple fields using regex (text searching, but mongo text indexes don't allow partial search)

Everything works fine when I make big OR Criteria

```
    Criteria().orOperator(
            Criteria.where(fieldOne).regex(search, caseInsensitive),
            Criteria.where(fieldTwo).regex(search, caseInsensitive),
            ..
```

But probably this could be made smoother if I used: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/

My problem is when I trying to use this in java like that:

```
Aggregation.addFields()
        .addField("\$fullText")
        .withValueOfExpression("\$concat", fieldOne, fieldTwo, ..
```

MongoTemplate sees only first param from above function
`MongoTemplate : Executing aggregation: [{ "$addFields" : { "fullText" : "$concat"}},`

Funny because if I write this like that:

```
        .addField("\$fullText")
        .withValueOfExpression(fieldOne, fieldTwo, "\$concat", ..
```

It returns me result filtered only by `fieldOne` and query looks like that:  `MongoTemplate : Executing aggregation: [{ "$addFields" : { "fullText" : "$fieldOne"}},`

Did anyone have similar problem?
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: Spring Data MongoDB [Full Text Queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.textsearch).

Comment: @prasad_ will this search for phrases like "coff" and "cak"? I'm not sure